# Why is desire "a commodity [Lucifer is] short on"?

Tags: character-analysis, comics, lucifer, mike-carey

In *The Sandman Presents: Lucifer - The Morningstar Option* #3 (written by Mike Carey and drawn by Scott Hampton), Lucifer explains he needed Rachel Begai to channel her desire to destroy the Velleity, as he himself is short on desire:

[image: Lucifer: "The Velleity was designed to satisfy desire. It's a commodity I'm short on, but yours did well enough. When you wished it gone, it had no choice but to destroy itself. By the way, you'll be needing this."]
 <sub>Click for full resolution.</sub>

At that point Lucifer has his hidden agenda, namely getting the Letter of Passage from Yahweh - he wouldn't go to all the trouble of fighting the Velleity otherwise.

Getting the Letter serves other means - breaking free of Yahweh's Creation, and of his omniscience and omnipresence. This is what Lucifer wants, or *desires* (as explained later, from the start of creation) - he doesn't show interest in anything else, and everything he does in the *Lucifer* comics series is for that one goal.

This was also acknowledged in the last issue of the series:

[image: "You've been unhappy because you've desired things that cannot be." Lucifer: "That's what desire is. The need for what we can't have. The need for what's readily available is called greed."]
 <sub>Click for full resolution.</sub>

**So why is Lucifer short on desire?** How does that fit in the rest of the series? Is my understanding of his character wrong?

Answer (score 2):

### Lucifer is cold and calculating

Morningstar does not "desire" - he plans and gets what he wants, not "wishes" and "hopes" to get it - there is no passion, so no desire, just cold calculation. There you have Rachel that is full of passion - she regrets that she is responsible for the death of her brother, so she hopes and **desires** to fix her mistake by killing the Velleity.

Comment: I don't completely agree - Lucifer is calculating, yes, but that doesn't mean he doesn't _want_ to break free, or doesn't desire it.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I think its a matter of definition of "desire" - even when you are hungry you don't "desire" food, because you can go to the fridge and get something. But when you are starving in the middle of the ocean, slice of dry bread would be something you'd kill for. Rachel would do anything to get her brother back; Lucifer is quite content as a "Lux" owner, at this stage of the story the whole "break free" is more of a distant plan (if I remember right, he was quite surprised that God kept his promise and gave him the ticket out).

Comment: He wasn't - he knew all along it was Yahweh's plan to 1) have Lucifer rebel and rule Hell 2) give Lucifer the Letter of Passage 3) have Elaine take over the whole thing. I think the actual reason Lucifer says he doesn't "desire" is because he, of all people, knows everything in Yahweh's creation has been pre-determined - so his own will or desire has no meaning.